# Vue.js 2 / Webpack Part disable Prefetch - Cannot call .tap() on a plugin that has not yet been defined. Call plugin('prefetch').use(<Plugin>) first

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, prefetch

I have a piece of config in my `vue.config.js` file which is intended to prevent Vue from prefetching files that are dynamically loaded.

The code looks like this...

```js
    chainWebpack: config => {
        // stop webpack from prefetching all possible themes
        config
            .plugin('prefetch')
            .tap(args => {
                args[0].fileBlacklist = [ /\/scheme-.*\./ ]
                return args
            })
    }
```

After doing an npm package update to resolve security vulnerabilities this does not work anymore and I get this error when trying to execute the app...

> Error: Cannot call .tap() on a plugin that has not yet been defined.
> Call plugin('prefetch').use() first.

I'm not sure what to do from here.